# Share desktop in Windows Netmeeting

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, screen-sharing, remote-connection, netmeeting

We are using "netmeeting" in XP home pc. But every time(Once in a day) we have to accept the call, share the desktop& set as automatically accept the calls(By going to that pc). Any alternate solution for this (Like by running script etc)? One more option is password protected connections.But in that only one user can log on at a time. Please tell me if any solution is available. That will be more helpful for me

Comment: In what context are you using NetMeeting?

Comment: We are using that pc as a testing pc, So more than 2 people need to use that pc simultaneously.